# How can I avoid duplicate items in a checkListBox

Tags: c#

I am working on my windows form application using c#. I have a checkListBox that is binded to db. I am wondering is there a way to delete any duplicate record from the database?

Here is my code

```
 private void fill_checkListBox()
 {
     try
     {
         string query = "select * from table_1 ";

         SqlCommand myTeacherCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConn);

         //reading the value from the query
         dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
         //Reading all the value one by one
         teacherCB.Items.Clear();


         while (dr.Read())
         {
             string name = dr.IsDBNull(2) ? string.Empty : dr.GetString(2);

             teacherCB.Items.Add(name);

             if (!checkBox.Items.Contains(name))
             {
                  teacherCB.Items.Add(name);
             }           
         }
         dr.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
 }
```

Comment: where are you assigning to the checklistbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first answer - use [DISTINCT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132161(v=sql.120).aspx) in query:

```
select distinct * from table_1
```

Also, I advice you to specify column names in query:

```
select distinct ID, Name from table_1
```

But I don't know anything about your data in table.

Comment: I should've mentioned before, I have my employee name the same record, but they purchase different items. Therefore in my checkListBox, I have duplicate employee.

Comment: @DragonBorn glad to know. can you accept the answer?